# Scope constants to an rspec context

Tags: rspec, constants, rspec2

I often want to do

```
context "empty stack" do
  SOME_CONSTANT = "value"
  it "should be empty" do
    # use SOME_CONSTANT
  end
end

context "populated stack" do
  SOME_CONSTANT = "a different value"
  it "should have some items" do
    # use SOME_CONSTANT
  end
end
```

ruby doesn't scope constants to closures so they leak out. Does anyone have a trick for declaring constants that are scoped to a context?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Change the declaration of the constant:
from `SOME_CONSTANT = "value"`
to `self::SOME_CONSTANT = "value"`

RSpec creates an anonymous class for each set of specs (context in your example) that it comes across. Declaring a constant without `self::` in an anonymous class makes it available in global scope, and is visible to all the specs. Changing the constant declaration to `self::` ensures that it is visible only within the anonymous class.

Comment: To use those constants inside an `it` block do: `self.class::SOME_CONSTANT`

Answer (score 25):

Having used rspec for longer now I think the more idiomatic approach is to use let.

```
context "empty stack" do
  let(:some_constant){ "value" }

  it "should be empty" do
    puts some_constant
  end
end

context "populated stack" do
  let(:some_constant){ "a different value" }

  it "should have some items" do
    puts some_constant
  end
end
```

Comment: I totally recommend using the `let` constructs. Read more about `let` here: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let

Comment: I want to use `let` but it's not available in the before blocks.

Comment: That's not true.  Definitions with `let` are available in `before`, `before(:each)` and `before(:suite)`. They only don't work with `before(:all)`.

Comment: `before(:all)` exact the case why I am here :)

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do it is to use `stub_const`

```rb
RSpec.describe "stubbing FOO" do
  it "can stub undefined constant FOO" do
    stub_const("FOO", 5)
    expect(FOO).to eq(5)
  end

  it "undefines the constant when the example completes" do
    expect { FOO }.to raise_error(NameError)
  end
end
```

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-9/docs/mutating-constants/stub-undefined-constant